# MPI_Send does not fail with destination -1

Tags: mpi, mpich

I am encountering some strange behavior with MPICH. The following minimal example, which sends a message to the non-existing process with rank -1, causes a deadlock:

```
// Program: send-err
#include <mpi.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
        MPI_Init(NULL, NULL);
 
        int world_rank;
        MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_rank);
        int world_size;
        MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_size);
        
        // We are assuming at least 2 processes for this task
        if (world_size != 2) {
                fprintf(stderr, "World size must be 2 for %s\n", argv[0]);
                MPI_Abort(MPI_COMM_WORLD, 1);
        }
        
        int number;
        if (world_rank == 0) {
                number = -1;
                MPI_Send(&number, // data buffer
                        1, // buffer size 
                        MPI_INT, // data type
                        -1, //destination
                        0, //tag
                        MPI_COMM_WORLD); // communicator
        } else if (world_rank == 1) {
                MPI_Recv(&number, 
                        1, // buffer size
                        MPI_INT, // data type
                        0, // source
                        0, //tag
                        MPI_COMM_WORLD, // communicator
                        MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
        }
        
        MPI_Finalize();
}
```

If the call to the send function,

```
MPI_Send( start, count, datatype, destination_rank, tag, communicator )
```

uses `destination_rank = -2`, then the program fails with the error message:

```
> mpirun -np 2 send-err 
Abort(402250246) on node 0 (rank 0 in comm 0): Fatal error in PMPI_Send: Invalid rank, error stack:
PMPI_Send(157): MPI_Send(buf=0x7fffeb411b44, count=1, MPI_INT, dest=MPI_ANY_SOURCE, tag=0, MPI_COMM_WORLD) failed
PMPI_Send(94).: Invalid rank has value -2 but must be nonnegative and less than 2
```

Based on the error message, I would expect a program that sends a message to the process with rank -1 to fail similarly to the program sending a message to the process with rank -2. What causes this difference in behavior?

Comment: from `mpi.h` on MPICH: `#define MPI_PROC_NULL   (-1)`

Comment: I have found this to be a very unfortunate choice on more than one occasion.

Comment: That had never occurred to me but, yes, -1 is a **terrible** choice. I was teaching a class the other week and wanted to show that sending to an invalid rank was one of the few times you get a really useful error message from MPI. I hacked a piece of code but it didn't complain as expected - looking back, it was probably sending to rank -1 :(

Comment: You'll see that the choice of `MPI_ANY_SOURCE=-2` for this implementation also makes the error message that the user gets a little confusing: `Fatal error in PMPI_Send: ... , count=1, MPI_INT, dest=MPI_ANY_SOURCE`